# How to call Users controller's method from any custom component with argument?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, mvc

Can any one suggest how I can call the Users default controller's methods, like activate or any other, that I have created in User controller of Admin site with argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would not call the controller methods to activate a user as this would then set a redirect as well - you need to be calling the model. Basic PHP, not really Joomla related.

So you would first include the model

```
include_once JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_users/models/user.php';
```

and then instantiate the object:

```
$usersMdl = new UsersModelUser();
```

define your array of user ids to activate (as only variables can be passed by reference):

```
$myIds = [1, 2, 3];
```

and then call the models methods:

```
$usersMdl->activate($myIds);
```

where 1,2 and 3 are the user ids you want to activate.

(code tested and working in Joomla 3.4+)